# Copying graph from Excel to Word with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, graph, automation, copy

I am trying to copy a graph from excel to word. The source file in excel has two sheets, 'data' & 'graph' on the 'graph' sheet there are 4 graphs, arranged 2x2.
The Word document is empty.

I am fairly new to powershell, but i want to automate a weekly report i have to make. This might seem a little steep, but i like a challenge. Plus, the report eats my time.

This is my code:

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application 
$xl.Visible = $true

$wb = $xl.workbooks.open("H:\Reporting\ULTRAgraphTest.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.worksheets.item(1)
$charts = $ws.ChartObjects()
$chart = $charts.Item(1)
$a = $chart.copy

$wd = new-object -comobject Word.application
$wd.visible = $true
$path = "H:\Reporting\insertest.docx"
$doc = $wd.documents.open($path)
$wd.selection.Paste()
```

When i run this, the files get opened, but it pastes the clipboard content in the word document. It doesn't seem to copy the graph. What am i not seeing here?

Comment: Why would you do this with PowerShell instead of with Word or Excel?  Also, why would you have an empty Word document saved?  The easiest way is probably to use Excel VBA to create a new document and move the *charts* at the same time, using one application to accomplish this instead of three.

Comment: I use an empty document to check if it works. I have a report template. I am doing this with powershell as I need to more than just these graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the partheses

```
$a = $chart.copy
```

Should be

```
$a = $chart.copy()
```